# npm install permission denied (macOS)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

To install a Bootstrap theme I want to run npm install. However I always receive a permission denied error.

I already tried `nvm` and then switched with `nvm use 10.9.0` to run `npm install`.

I also tried `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`and `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Neither solved it and now I am bit out of ideas how I can continue. I use macOS High Sierra.

```
Marcs-MBP-3:masterclass Marc$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated gulp-uglifyjs@0.6.2: Since gulp-sourcemaps now works, use gulp-uglify instead
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update! 
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules
npm ERR! path /Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Marc/.npm/_logs/2018-08-22T12_46_51_786Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The solutions here are all "how"s to solve this, but none of them answers as to "why" this error is happening, does anyone know?? 

I encountered this sort of permission denied issue when trying to install some other library from github.

Comment: How did you install `node` on your machine? `which node` may give more information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check permissions of your project root with `ls -l /Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/masterclass/`. If the owner is not `$USER`, delete your `node_modules` directory, try changing the owner of that directory instead and run `npm install` again.

```
cd /Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev
rm -rf ./masterclass/node_mdoules/
chown -R $USER ./masterclass/
cd masterclass    
npm install
```

Answer (score 163):

For Mac;

Run this on the Terminal >

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: Can confirm, ran into this issue on Mac OS Catalina and this solved the issue

Comment: This corrects the issue on MacOS High Sierra as well.

Comment: I also tried this today, and it worked for me, using Mac OS Catalina ‍♂️

Comment: On Big Sur, sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin

Comment: This fixed my problem in Mac

Comment: Works on Mac OS monterey as well

Comment: Didn't work for me. I'm using macOS Monterey v12.5

Comment: Workd for me on monterey 12.6

Comment: Months without updating firebase-tools and this command fixed it, thanks, working on MAC OS ventura

Comment: Works on Ventura 13.1

Comment: This did not work for me on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 35):

KIndly run the below commands:

1. To check the location of the package:

   `npm config get prefix`
2. Then run this :

   `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`
3. Enter the password and run installation commands

It worked for me.

Comment: Correct solution for my case.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me, thanks

Comment: can confirm this worked for me on Ventura.

Comment: after uploading Big Sur had a zillion problems....the above 2 commands allowed me to see my React App after staring at a blank screen for 48 hours...kudos

Answer (score 33):

I tried everything in this thread with no luck on Big Sur, but then I tried this:

```
sudo npm install -g yarn
```

And it worked!

Comment: After a day tried, i solved my issue. thanks @Meowsleydale

Comment: This worked for me on Sonoma with gulp-cli

Answer (score 7):

For me it was,

```
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

I tried deleting manually but didn't help

Answer (score 5):

For Macs running Big Sur or Monterey:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue - except my path was "usr/local/lib".

Answer (score 2):

I did this for nodemon and it work

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

then install the packages that you need

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, but the accepted answer did not work for me, so I will post my solution in case anyone else comes along needing it.

I was running `npm install` in a project cloned from GitHub and during the clone, for whatever reason the write permission was not actually set on the project directory. To check if this is your problem, pull up Terminal and enter the following:

```
cd path/to/project/parent/directory
ls -l
```

If the directory has user write access, the output will include a `w` in the first group of permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 user  staff  480 Sep 10 12:21 project-name
```

This assumes that you're trying to access a project in the home directory structure of the current user. To make sure that the current user owns the project directory, follow the instructions in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I entered the following:

```sh
cd /Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev
rm -rf ./masterclass/node_mdoules/
chown -R $USER ./masterclass/
cd masterclass    
npm install
```

once this was completed the results indicated warnings and one notice instead of previous result of no permission and error.

I then entered the following:

```sh
% sudo npm install --global firebase-tools
```

my result was success upon completion of the last terminal entry.

Comment: awesome, I had the firebase-tools installation problem as well

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem because i install it from pkg, and i solve this problem use below step:

```sh
1. sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/
2. brew doctor
3. brew cleanup --prune-prefix ( or sudo rm -f /usr/local/include/node)
4. brew install node
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this command :
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
Gave password and worked for mw. Took 10 secs to install angular

Answer (score 1):

Ok my problem was that I thought I was installing on the path:

```
/Users/mauro/Documents/dev/react
```

Where my project was setup, but instead I was doing it on:

```
Users/mauro/Documents/dev/
```

One path higher and that is why it did not perform the installation in my case.

I simply did: `cd react` and voila I was able to install without problem

Answer (score 0):

`NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`

Copy this line into ur terminal, then hit enter. Then install the necessary packages you need WITHOUT the term "sudo" in front of npm.

i.e.,

```
npm install -g jshint
```

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that work on me `sudo npm i -g clasp --unsafe-perm`

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
sudo npm install -g @sanity/cli && sanity init
```

it will ask sudo password and you are good to go

Answer (score -1):

That is because you dont have the "node modules". You can install with this code:

```
npm install -g node-modules
```

then, create your react app with `npm init react-app my-app`

Answer (score -1):

Run on macOS Terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin
```

It will ask for the password then you're good to go!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

for me:

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/giasin/.npm"
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35671644)