# Vue.js localhost giving a permission error

Tags: vue.js, localhost

I have a Vue app that works on one (Windows) machine, but not on another (Mac) machine. The non-working one just gives a message "You do not have permission to access this app" in the browser.

The only error in the console is

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

Any ideas? All my other Vue apps work fine

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information about what exactly you're doing that you're getting that error and where. That being said, this is likely not a Vue.js issue, rather a Mac OS issue with permissions. See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967335/npm-install-permission-denied-macos) is related.

Additionally, the URL from the console https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/popper.min.js.map returns `Cannot find package` message, so it is indeed incorrect, the correct URL would probably be https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2/dist/umd/popper.min.js.map