# Using npm always gives a warning: npm WARN logfile could not be created

Tags: node.js, npm

I can use the functions of npm normally, but there will always be this warning after each execution result. Is there a way to remove this warning?

```
$ node -v
v18.0.0

$ npm -v
npm WARN logfile could not be created: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/hehe/.npm/_logs/2022-05-02T11_06_01_461Z-debug-0.log'
8.8.0

$ npm install bootstrap
npm WARN logfile could not be created: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/hehe/.npm/_logs/2022-05-02T11_15_13_625Z-debug-0.log'

added 2 packages, and audited 4 packages in 2s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

my os: macOS Monterey version 12.0.1

I have try the answers to this question, but is still doesn't work: [npm install permission denied (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967335/npm-install-permission-denied-macos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install permission denied (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967335/npm-install-permission-denied-macos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM / Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952903/npm-error-eacces-permission-denied-scandir)

Comment: @LironZ No, what I get is a warning, not an error, and doesn't affect normal use.

Comment: @HawkChou,  I understand, but there is an error while trying to create a log file, which is not critical for NPM and reported by it as a warning. I think that the underlying issue is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it.
I had installed node and npm via brew and suspect that this set the log folder owner to **root**. This resulted in the problem with the access rights.

I had to correct the access rights for the log folder with the following command (replace USERNAME with your own):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_logs
```

In your case:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/hehe/.npm/_logs
```

I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

the log says that there is no correct access rights for the directory
`/Users/hehe/.npm/_logs/2022-05-02T11_06_01_461Z-debug-0.log`, try:

```
>  sudo chmod 777 /Users/hehe/.npm/_logs/2022-05-02T11_06_01_461Z-debug-0.log
```

or, in case it does not fix your issue, try this `cmd line`:

```
> sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

More Informations here [npm install permission denied (macOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51967335/npm-install-permission-denied-macos)

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: run `npm cache clean --force` before `npm start` or `npm run start` ?

Comment: same as before :(

Comment: have you tried to install  `yarn` :   `npm install --global yarn`  then `yarn --version && yarn start` (`yarn` is a bit better than `npm`)

Comment: this guy had the same issues running  `npm run build` https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template/issues/579, and from what I've red, perhaps  Try this:

    remove node_modules and package-lock.json, 
    remove dist folder, 
    then run: 1.`npm cache clean`
    2.`npm install`
    3.`npm run start`
Hope it helps :)